# Is $(\log n)^3$ the same as $\log^3 n$?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I saw the notation

[image]

Where I would have expected $(\log n)^3$.

Are both the same? Just a different style?

Comment: Yes it is correct. It is also like $(\sin x)^2=\sin^2 x$..

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: Yes, these are the same... Same for $\sin^3 x = (\sin{x})^3$

Comment: What else could they mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It could mean $\log(\log(\log( n )))$

Comment: @miracle173: of course but I was asking the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. Actually the notation $\log^3 n$ should mean the composition of $\log$ with itself three times, meaning $\log \log \log n$, to be coherent with the fact that some inverses are denoted as, for example, $\sin^{-1} x$, but for a conventions reasons it is accepted that $\log^3 n =(\log n)^3$.

Comment: Note that $\sin^{-1}{x}$ is only used in English math literature (which is confusing and ambiguous). In the east we use always $\arcsin$, at least that's what I've seen in all textbooks.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Yes, I use $\arcsin$ as well, however with a generic function $f$ the only possibility is to use $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that for $\sin$ or say for $\tan$, not for a general function.