# what the definition of $\log^bn$?

Tags: logarithms

I'm learning a math post [How limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \log^bn }{n^a} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913660/how-limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac-logbn-na-0) and being stuck at $\log^bn$.

I've skimmed the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) page but didn't find a clue.

Could some help me on this?

Comment: Same idea as $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3908422/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $(\log n)^b$, which we don't write as $\log n^b$ as that's $b\log n$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $f^n(x)$ means $\left( f(x) \right)^n.$

So, $\sin^n(x)$ means $\left( \sin(x) \right)^n,\ $ which can also be written as $\left( \sin x \right)^n,\quad $ $\log^n(x)$ means $\left( \log(x) \right)^n\ $ which can also be written as $\left( \log x \right)^n\ $ etc etc

Comment: Although $f^n$ may also denote function concatenation, with $f^{-1}$ an inverse. Hopefully, however, concatenation uses the notation $f^{\circ n}$.